# Magento 2.2 refused to apply stylesheet

Tags: magento2.2

On our **Magento 2.2.2** based website we are setting up, we are getting the below 2 error messages (in google console).
 I have seen only one other post on the site about this issue and based on what I have read made sure the **.htaccess** file is in the **pub/static folder** I also changed the file ownership and also. The file permissions to 777 recursively.

However, still getting the same error?
Any suggestions?

```
Refused to apply style from '/pub/static/frontend/Smartwave/porto_child/en_US/css/styles-l.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

Refused to apply style from '/pub/static/frontend/Smartwave/porto_child/en_US/css/styles-m.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your css hasn't been deployed.

```
its MIME type ('text/html')
```

indicates that it's (probably) a 404. Have you run setup:static-content:deploy?

Comment: The site is in developer mode so deploy is not needed?? However you are right I don't see the files at the above path. Maybe i should just download them and upload them to the above path?

Comment: You can't download the files, they have to be deployed. Since your path indicates it's a third-party time, you'd be better served with doing a force deploy (setup:static-content:deploy -f) so that the CSS files are generated.